# FFmpeg 0.8 - Compile library to convert mp2 to mp4

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Basically, I have a very specific use-case. I need to convert mp2 video into mp4.

Input Video:

```
Codec: MPEG-1/2 Video (mpgv)
Resolution: 720x576
Frame rate: 50
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
```

Input Audio:

```
Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1/2/3 (mpga)
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 48000 Hz
Bitrate: 192 kb/s
```

I am using Android, and I am using [this tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/) (it uses 0.8, that is why I am using that version) to compile FFmpeg for Android. So far I have created a .so successfully and can run ndk-build to compile a .c jni file.

The call to:

```
av_open_input_file(&gFormatCtx, gFileName, NULL, 0, NULL)
```

Generates:

```
06-12 08:53:22.570: E/FFmpegTest(1219): Error open video file: -1094995529
```

I do not understand this error, and googling returns nothing helpful. Does anyone know what may be causing it?

Also as a second option, I started looking into the examples provided in FFmpeg. The decoding_encoding.c specifically. Unfortunately, this file references a "channel_layout.h" which does not exist in my includes after compile. (I noticed I was looking at modern FFmpeg examples. I opened the 0.8 version example and it is different. I will look at that first)

Comment: You have to search for that error code without the minus sign to get much.   It is the #define for AVERROR_INVALIDDATA.    See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944133/how-can-i-find-out-what-this-ffmpeg-error-code-means/28834523#28834523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried lots of tutorials but the one that worked for me was this one (and it is a lot newer), then I used avformat_open_input to open it:

http://bambuser.com/opensource

Please also post how you are creating gFormatCtx and the gFileName value!

I followed this tutorial, even though it is for an old version, it is great to learn:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg

Comment: I will look at bambuser.com. I think what I am working with is probably the worst case. I shouldn't work purposely with old-deprecated libraries. I will research on bambuser for a little bit.

Comment: Do you have any example code / tutorial that you used to learn. I don't want to be using samples for deprecated code if I can avoid it.

Comment: This is the best tutorial ever (even though it is outdated, it is the best one): http://dranger.com/ffmpeg

Comment: Looks like a good start - an easy to use library and an extensive tutorial. Many thanks.