# How can I found FFmpeg Error code's meaning?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have an issue using FFMPEG.

`avcodec_send_packet()` is returning error code -12.

I am trying to find what the meaning of -12 is.

I found this page but I can't understand the calculation for -12:

[How can I find out what this ffmpeg error code means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944133/)

Can anyone help me?

I'm using DXVA2 for decoding. and `avcodec_send_packet()` function is return -12 after the 20th frame.

20th frame return

[image]

21st frame return

[image]

Comment: `AVERROR_INVALIDDATA` isn't all that explicit, but provides a small hint. There is invalid data in the input. What and where, I can't say, but if you can build a [mcve], maybe a ffmpeg guru might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [`avcodec_send_packet()` documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga58bc4bf1e0ac59e27362597e467efff3), it says:

> **Returns**
>
> 0 on success, otherwise negative error code: `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`: input is not accepted in the current state - user must read output with `avcodec_receive_frame()` (once all output is read, the packet should be resent, and the call will not fail with `EAGAIN`). `AVERROR_EOF`: the decoder has been flushed, and no new packets can be sent to it (also returned if more than 1 flush packet is sent) `AVERROR(EINVAL)`: codec not opened, it is an encoder, or requires flush `AVERROR(ENOMEM)`: failed to add packet to internal queue, or similar other errors: legitimate decoding errors

Note that `avcodec_send_packet()` is returning error codes based on the `AVERROR()` macro, which is defined in `libavutil/error.h` as:

```
/* error handling */
#if EDOM > 0
#define AVERROR(e) (-(e))   ///< Returns a negative error code from a POSIX error code, to return from library functions.
#define AVUNERROR(e) (-(e)) ///< Returns a POSIX error code from a library function error return value.
#else
/* Some platforms have E* and errno already negated. */
#define AVERROR(e) (e)
#define AVUNERROR(e) (e)
#endif
```

As you can see in the documentation, standard POSIX error codes are being passed to `AVERROR()`.

Now, if you go look at the POSIX error codes defined in your compiler's `errno.h` header, you'll find that `[-]12` is defined as `ENOMEM`, which is one of the possible values mentioned in the `avcodec_send_packet()` documentation:

> `AVERROR(ENOMEM)`: failed to add packet to internal queue, or similar other errors: legitimate decoding errors

Which, according to [this version of `error.h`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/error_8h-source.html) (as opposed to [this version](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/error_8h_source.html)) says:

```
#if LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MAJOR < 51
#define AVERROR_INVALIDDATA AVERROR(EINVAL)  
...
#define AVERROR_NOMEM       AVERROR(ENOMEM)  
...
#endif
```

The screenshots you have shown are testing the return value of `avcodec_send_packet()` for `AVERROR_INVALIDDATA` instead of `AVERROR_NOMEM`.

Comment: Thanks .How I match 12 and AVERROR(ENOMEM) in libavutil/error.h?

Comment: Oh. I can find int errno.h . Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg has the 'av_strerror' function in the 'libavutil/error.h' file. You can find the error string as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/error.h> 
}

int main()
enter code here {
    char temp[256];
    int result = -1094995529;
    av_strerror(result, temp, 256);
    std::cout << "Error: " << temp << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

This code snippet demonstrates how to use 'av_strerror' to obtain the error string for a given error code. Simply replace the 'result' variable with your specific error code.