# what is ffmpeg exit code 2? and also output error array is empty and not working in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to convert bitrate to 128 but not working in php

```
 exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k output().mp3 2>&1", 
 $output, $exit_code);
 if ($exit_code!= 0) {
    $data['message'][] = "Error";
 }

 print_r($output);
 print_r($exit_code);
 exit;
```

After running this code show error code 2.
The output is an empty array and also exit_code is 2 and not create output.mp3 file.

I already study [How can I find out what this ffmpeg error code means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944133/how-can-i-find-out-what-this-ffmpeg-error-code-means) but this isn't my problem and don't explain error code 2 or error code 2 is not defined. My problem is dont show any error and error message is empty just exit_code show 2 that means is some error happened.

Comment: Try just to run this command manually in terminal and check the output.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the reply I tried but not work.

Comment: not work - what are the error messages there?

Comment: @Alex error message is an empty array.

Comment: there is no such thing as `empty array` error message when you run `ffmpeg` manually in terminal

Comment: @Alex thanks for helping run original code in terminal and know what happened.  syntax error near unexpected token `('. In my code output have () and in PHP show empty array after running in the terminal show above error thanks a lot.

Comment: so that means that ffmpeg does not allow your file name `output().mp3` fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## syntax error near unexpected token `('

You need to escape the parentheses because they are special characters:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k 'output().mp3' 2>&1",
```

or

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k output\(\).mp3 2>&1",
```

Also see [FFmpeg: Quoting & Escaping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping).

This isn't exactly a PHP issue, so please always make sure your `ffmpeg` command works **before** you attempt to script it. (That would really reduce the number of questions here.)